# AngularJS route does not render the template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have two controllers and I'm using the AngularJS `$routeProvider` to load multiple pages. When I click on the link from the first partial to go the second one, the second partial does not render, and the template tags are all that show.

So, in the first partial, this renders to Hello World:

`<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`

But, this doesn't render on the second partial:

`<h1>Hello {{name}} on page 2</h1>`

Here's a plunkr to show what I mean: http://plnkr.co/edit/7X2vlIhMvLlIqE4UvC09?p=preview

Comment: Might want to check your error console next time ~ *"ReferenceError: $routeParams is not defined"*. Looks like you aren't injecting `$routeParams` into your controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not injecting `$routeParams` to your controller. Inject it to your controller like:

```
app.controller("UserDetailCtrl", function($scope, $routeParams) {
```

This will solve your issue

In your controller you named the scope variable as `$scope.name2` and in your partial2.html page you are binding to `{{name}}`. That is the problem. Change it to `{{name2}}` or either change your scope variable to `$scope.name`

Comment: I thought this too but it doesn't appear to be working on the *plnkr* demo

Comment: Ya it is working for me. After doing this when clicking on user name it is rendering the partial2.html page

Comment: Never mind, OP has `$scope.name2` instead of `$scope.name` in their controller

Comment: Yes thats the issue. I just checked it.